# Tranposing data in listview vertically using VB6

Tags: listview, vb6

Can someone help me because i am stuck in my project.

I have a `CSV file` that will parse in `VB6` and can viewed in `ListView`. I can already put the data in listview but the problem is it is horizontally like this

```
Mango, Apple, Grapes, Orange, Pineapple
Water, Milk, Soft drinks, Tea, Fruit drinks
Cellphone, Television, Radio, Telephone
```

what I need is to view the data `VERTICALLY` like this

```
Mango           Water               Cellphone
Apple           Milk                Television
Grapes          Soft drinks         Radio
Orange          Tea                 Telephone
Pineapple       Fruit drinks        Laptop
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why ListView and not one of the FlexGrid controls?

Comment: listview can accommodate many data unlike Flexgrid.